# Eigenvalues of a general 4x4 matrix with 16 independent variables.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose the following matrix:

$$
M=\pmatrix{a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\\i&j&k&k\\m&n&o&p}
$$

I am trying to solve this but the problem does not seem to have a short and sweet solution. I was wondering what can be done to improve the elegance of the solution further. Are there any known symmetries that can simplify the solution, for a problem of this type?

---

For reference, requesting the eigenvalues in Mathematica via

```
M=({
 {a, b, c, d},
 {e, f, g, h},
 {i, j, k, l},
 {m, n, o, p}
});
M//MatrixForm
Part[Eigenvalues[M],1]
ToRadicals[%]
```

The line M= `Part[Eigenvalues[M],1]` returns:

```
Root[d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - 
   d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
   d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
   c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
   a f k p + (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
      b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - 
      h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - 
      f k p) #1 + (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
      l o + a p + f p + k p) #1^2 + (-a - f - k - p) #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]
```

And the line `ToRadicals[%]` returns:

```
1/4 (a + f + k + p) - 
 1/2 \[Sqrt](b e - a f + c i + g j - a k - f k + d m + h n + l o + 
     1/4 (-a - f - k - p)^2 - a p - f p - k p + 
     1/3 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p +
         f p + k p) + (2^(
        1/3) ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
            a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
          3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - 
             a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
             h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
             a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
          12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
             b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
             c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
             a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
             c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + a f k p)))/(3 (2 (-b e + 
             a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + 
             f p + k p)^3 - 
          9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - 
             d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - 
             c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - 
             c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
             a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - 
             f k p) + 
          27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
             b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
             d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
             g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
          27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
             b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
             d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
             b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
             c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
             a f k p) - 
          72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
             a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m +
              c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - 
             a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - 
             d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + 
             b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
             a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
                3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + 
                   b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                   d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                   a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                   a k p - f k p) + 
                12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
                   b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
                   c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
                   a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
                   c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                   a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
               9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - 
                  b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
                  b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - 
                  g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
                  a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
               27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
                  d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
                  h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + 
                  b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
               27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
                  b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
                  d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
                  b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
                  c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                  a f k p) - 
               72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
                  l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - 
                  d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                  c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                  d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                  a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                  b e k p + a f k p))^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
     3 2^(1/3)))((2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
          l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
       9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - 
          h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + 
          a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
          d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + 
          f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
       27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
          b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
          d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
          g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
       27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
          c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
          c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + 
          b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
          b e k p + a f k p) - 
       72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
          a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
          c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
          c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + 
          b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
          b e k p + 
          a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k -
                d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
             3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + 
                b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                a k p - f k p) + 
             12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
                b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
                c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
                a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
                c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e +
                a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + 
               f p + k p)^3 - 
            9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - 
               d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - 
               c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m -
                c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - 
               h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p -
                a k p - f k p) + 
            27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
               d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n -
                g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
               a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
            27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
               b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
               d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
               b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
               c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
               a f k p) - 
            72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o +
                a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
               b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
               d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
               b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
               c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
               a f k p))^2))^(1/3))) - 
 1/2 \[Sqrt](b e - a f + c i + g j - a k - f k + d m + h n + l o + 
     1/2 (-a - f - k - p)^2 - a p - f p - k p + 
     1/3 (b e - a f + c i + g j - a k - f k + d m + h n + l o - a p - 
        f p - k p) - (2^(
        1/3) ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
            a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
          3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - 
             a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
             h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
             a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
          12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
             b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
             c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
             a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
             c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + a f k p)))/(3 (2 (-b e + 
             a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + 
             f p + k p)^3 - 

          9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - 
             d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - 
             c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - 
             c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
             a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - 
             f k p) + 
          27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
             b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
             d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
             g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
          27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
             b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
             d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
             b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
             c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
             a f k p) - 
          72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
             a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m +
              c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - 
             a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - 
             d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + 
             b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
             a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
                3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + 
                   b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                   d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                   a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                   a k p - f k p) + 
                12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
                   b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
                   c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
                   a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
                   c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                   a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
               9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                  f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - 
                  b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
                  b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - 
                  g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
                  a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
               27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
                  d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
                  h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + 
                  b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
               27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
                  b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
                  d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
                  b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
                  c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                  a f k p) - 
               72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
                  l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - 
                  d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                  c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                  d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                  a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                  b e k p + a f k p))^2))^(1/3)) - (1/(
     3 2^(1/3)))((2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
          l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
       9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - 
          h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + 
          a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
          d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + 
          f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
       27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
          b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
          d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
          g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
       27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
          c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
          c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + 
          b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
          b e k p + a f k p) - 
       72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + 
          a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
          c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
          c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + 
          b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
          b e k p + 
          a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k -
                d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
             3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + 
                b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                a k p - f k p) + 
             12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
                b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
                c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
                a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
                c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e +
                a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + 
               f p + k p)^3 - 
            9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - 
               d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - 
               c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m -
                c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - 
               h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p -
                a k p - f k p) + 
            27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
               d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n -
                g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
               a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
            27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
               b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
               d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
               b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
               c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
               a f k p) - 
            72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o +
                a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
               b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
               d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
               b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
               c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
               a f k p))^2))^(
     1/3)) - (-(-a - f - k - p)^3 + 
        4 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m -
            h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) - 
        8 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
           b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
           d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
           g j p - a k p - f k p))/(4 \[Sqrt](b e - a f + c i + g j - 
           a k - f k + d m + h n + l o + 1/4 (-a - f - k - p)^2 - 
           a p - f p - k p + 
           1/3 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - l o +
               a p + f p + k p) + (2^(
              1/3) ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
                  l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
                3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + 
                   b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                   d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                   a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                   a k p - f k p) + 
                12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - 
                   b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - 
                   c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + 
                   a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + 
                   c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                   a f k p)))/(3 (2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                   f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
                9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                   f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - 
                   b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
                   b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - 
                   g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
                   a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
                27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
                   d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
                   h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + 
                   b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 
                27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
                   b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
                   d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
                   b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
                   c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                   a f k p) - 
                72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
                   l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - 
                   d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                   c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                   d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                   a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                   b e k p + 
                   a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + 
                    a k + f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + 
                    k p)^2 - 
                    3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + 
                    a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - 
                    c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - 
                    h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + 
                    g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
                    12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
                    c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - 
                    a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - 
                    d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + 
                    b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                    a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                    f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
                    9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k +
                     f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i -
                     b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
                    b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - 
                    g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
                    a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
                    27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - 
                    a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + 
                    a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + 
                    f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - 
                    f k p)^2 + 
                    27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - 
                    d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                    c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                    d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                    a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                    b e k p + a f k p) - 
                    72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - 
                    h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - 
                    d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                    c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                    d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                    a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                    b e k p + a f k p))^2))^(1/3)) + (1/(
           3 2^(1/3)))((2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - 
                h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
             9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - 
                d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - b g i - 
                c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + 
                d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - 
                d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + 
                c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
             27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
                d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
                h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + 
                b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p)^2 + 

             27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
                b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
                d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
                b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
                c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                a f k p) - 
             72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n - 
                l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + 
                b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + 
                d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - 
                b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - 
                c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                a f k p) + \[Sqrt](-4 ((-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k +
                     f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^2 - 
                   3 (-a - f - k - p) (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j +
                     b e k - a f k + d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - 
                    d e n + a h n + h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + 
                    a l o + f l o + b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - 
                    a k p - f k p) + 
                   12 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m + b h k m + 
                    c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n + d e k n - 
                    a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o - b h i o - 
                    d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o - c f i p + 
                    b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p + 
                    a f k p))^3 + (2 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                    f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p)^3 - 
                  9 (-a - f - k - p) (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + 
                    f k - d m - h n - l o + a p + f p + k p) (c f i - 
                    b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + d f m - 
                    b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + h k n - 
                    g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + b e p - 
                    a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - f k p) + 
                  27 (c f i - b g i - c e j + a g j + b e k - a f k + 
                    d f m - b h m + d k m - c l m - d e n + a h n + 
                    h k n - g l n - d i o - h j o + a l o + f l o + 
                    b e p - a f p + c i p + g j p - a k p - 
                    f k p)^2 + 
                  27 (-a - f - k - p)^2 (d g j m - c h j m - d f k m +
                     b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + c h i n +
                     d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + d f i o -
                     b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - a f l o -
                     c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - b e k p +
                     a f k p) - 
                  72 (-b e + a f - c i - g j + a k + f k - d m - h n -
                     l o + a p + f p + k p) (d g j m - c h j m - 
                    d f k m + b h k m + c f l m - b g l m - d g i n + 
                    c h i n + d e k n - a h k n - c e l n + a g l n + 
                    d f i o - b h i o - d e j o + a h j o + b e l o - 
                    a f l o - c f i p + b g i p + c e j p - a g j p - 
                    b e k p + a f k p))^2))^(1/3)))))
```

If I were to add a line `Simplify[%]` then it doesn't return in a reasonable time on my system.

Comment: The eigenvalues are the solutions of an equation of degree four. The formula for the solutions of $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$ are already quite messy. In your case, the coefficients of the polynomial are not simple literals like $a,b,c,d,e$, but complicated combinations of $16$ literals. It stands to reason that "short and sweet" solution isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is a fourth-degree polynomial where the coefficients are some combination of the entries of your matrix. The eigenvalues of your matrix are the roots of that polynomial. The general formula for those roots, even with the simplified coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, [is not pretty](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg) (that image is the formula for the roots of $x^4 + ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0$, consider what would happen if you swapped each letter there with the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial).

So it's no wonder that you get a complicated expression back, and I would much rather remember the algorithm to find eigenvalues than trying to actually memorize and use a formula.